# What is the ItemDecoration for Jetpack Compose LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, item-decoration, android-jetpack-compose-list

In JetpackCompose, we can use `LazyColumnFor` as `RecyclerView`.

In `RecyclerView`, to have a proper margin/padding between items, we need to use `ItemDecoration`, as per this [article](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/right-way-of-setting-margin-on-recycler-views-cell-319da259b641?source=friends_link&sk=6f0be4e29b67012f2e4e348a8c3d25e6)

Like below

```
class MarginItemDecoration(private val spaceHeight: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View,
                                parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        with(outRect) {
            if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
                top = spaceHeight
            }
            left =  spaceHeight
            right = spaceHeight
            bottom = spaceHeight
        }
    }
}
```

For JetpackCompose `LazyColumnFor`, what's the equivalent of `ItemDecoration`?

Comment: I've created a feature/documentation request for this here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188855907

Answer (score 121):

You can use the **`verticalArrangement`** parameter to add a spacing between each item using [**`Arrangement.spacedBy()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#spacedby_2).

Something like:

```
LazyColumn(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
) {
    // ...
}
```

The example below adds `8.dp` of space in-between each item

Before and after:
[image]
[image]

If you want to add padding around the edges of the content you can use the **`contentPadding`** parameter.

```
  LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 24.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
  ){ ...  }
```

In the example above, the first item will add `8.dp` padding to it’s top, the last item will add `8.dp` to its bottom, and all items will have `24.dp` padding on the left and the right.

[image]

Comment: That's nice. Thanks. Does it also allow any drawing in between (i.e. item decorator not only allows padding but also any drawing eg lines.)

Comment: @Elye Currently it provides only content spacing. The current workaround for other decorators is to put them inside the content in the `items/item` blocks.

Comment: The problem with using `contentPadding` is that any click animation will not reach to the edge and so will look bad. Better to put the padding inside each item modifier (after the click handler)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `LazyColumn` with `itemsIndexed` (formerly `LazyColumnForIndexed`, deprecated) and apply the padding depending on the index.

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
  itemsIndexed(items = ...) { index, item ->
    Box(Modifier.padding(
      start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp, top = if (index == 0) 16.dp else 0.dp
    ))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial comes from the code lab you should refer to for a good plan
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-layouts#6

```
LazyRow(
    modifier = modifier.padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)
) {
    items(alignYourBodyData) { item ->
        AlignYourBodyElement(
            drawable = item.drawable,
            text = item.text
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of workaround using `contentPadding` of `LazyColumnFor` for top, start and end padding, and `Spacer` as the bottom padding for all items.

```
@Composable
fun MyComposeList(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    listItems: List<String>,
) {
    LazyColumnFor(
        modifier = modifier, items = listItems,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp, 16.dp, 16.dp)
    ) { itemText ->
        ViewItem(
            itemText = itemText
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(16.dp))
    }
}
```

This seems to get the result I needed, as the `contentPadding` can be scrolled together within the `LazyColumnFor`